# XXHDPI Layout different on different XXHDPI devices

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm hoping someone could offer some advice.  I have developed an application and the UI was pretty complicated, so the standard layout of one folder wasn't sufficient.  I had to create a layout folder for each resolution.  So the folder layout is as follows:

[image: Folder Layout]

I had it as: 
layout - xxhdpi
layout - xhdpi

etc...

however, after reading an article on the developer website I changed it to the new layout.  However, I have been testing on a xxhdpi device (samsung s4) and the layout is perfect but I have received reports from a Sony Z3 user (also xxhpi) that the layout is off.  I have seen screen shots of how it looks on this device and it does not look right.

Is there something I'm missing, I thought if I developed a layout for xxhdpi device that it should fit all xxhdpi devices?

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: I guess you are facing the similar issue (https://stackoverflow.com/q/57287392/4754141)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

There mainly three various layout folder are created for multiple device and tab resolution support which are :

```
layout // for all devices
layout-sw600dp // for 7' tablet
layout-sw720dp // for 10' tablet
```

But you have to provide various images based on device resolution in drawable which are :

```
drawable // for common images
drawable-ldpi 
drawable-mdpi 
drawable-hdpi 
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```