# Android spacing issue in same resolution devices 1080x1920

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, spacing, android-screen-support

I am designing screen from Zeplin. *(Zeplin provides each item attributes in dp)*

Following is the **horizontal recycler view** design example with 4 items from Zeplin.

[image: zeplin]

> **360 dp means 1080 for xxhdpi devices**

[image: dp to px]

I am testing my code on two 1080 devices with different dpi

1. **Samsung c5** *[1080 x 1920 pixels, 16:9 ratio (480dpi)]*
2. **Nexus 5X** *[1080 x 1920 pixels, 16:9 ratio (420dpi)]*

> **I am facing spacing issue in Nexus-5x, the Zeplin design works great**
>   **on Samsung-c5.**

[image: Samsung c5 result]

> **Samsung-c5 result**

[image: Nexus 5x result]

> **Nexus-5x result - spacing issue in horizontal recycler view**

**QUESTION:**

**Why the design in different on same resolution (1080x1920) devices *(different dpi)*. How can I make it look same on each and every device like facebook does with its status**

---

Similar Questions:

1. [How to use 1080x1920: 420 dpi - Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449494/how-to-use-1080x1920-420-dpi-android-studio)
2. [Android xxhdpi, 420 dpi and 480 dpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253607/android-xxhdpi-420-dpi-and-480-dpi)
3. [XXHDPI Layout different on different XXHDPI devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462114/xxhdpi-layout-different-on-different-xxhdpi-devices)
4. [Sol1 - Calculator app different layout on same screen size but different DPI (420 DPI vs 480 DPI)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31220847/4754141) - [Android Developer](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/09/android-marshmallow-ready-for-devices.html)
5. [Sol2 - Android layout folders for different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437942/android-layout-folders-for-different-screen-sizes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing dimens in **values-w410dp** worked, as mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34758288/4754141)